# Why do I see so many frequent updates to the kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates

Is Ubuntu sending these unusually frequent updates or am I being "blessed" by the usual suspects ?

Why is now "unattended updates" installed when a cardinal reason for using Ubuntu was the wish to maintain a minimum of control over one's platform ?

Comment: linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic is getting security fixes: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-security-announce . The latest (at now) is: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2015-March/002853.html

Answer (score 3):

You'll receive frequent updates to the kernel, which is what the linux-image updates refer to, as it's always being worked on with a view to tightening security.

`unattended-upgrade` is installed by default, but when using the graphical installer, you can select 'no' to automatic updates, which means that it's not enabled. Alternatively there is an option to only install security updates.

If you want to retain very strict control over the packages you use, then don't use `unattended-upgrade`. The traditional `apt-get` update and upgrade route is the one to follow, which can be managed in a variety of ways, though editing your `/etc/apt/sources.list` is usually the simplest and most effective in my opinion.